# Quartus set optimization options per entity from VHDL source

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I want to set different synthesis settings for individual entities in Quartus. Specifically I want to change the [Auto Resource Sharing](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/logicops/logicops/def_auto_resource_sharing.htm) option. I managed to change this setting for an individual component using the Assignment Editor. This adds the following line to the QSF:

```
set_instance_assignment -name AUTO_RESOURCE_SHARING OFF -to "adder:inst73"
```

While this will work, it's hard to maintain these settings in the project. I would rather assign this setting directy in the VHDL source of the component. I tried the following attributes but it didn't seem to make a difference.

```
entity adder is
    -- ...
end entity;

architecture behaviour of adder is
    attribute altera_attribute : string;
    attribute altera_attribute of adder : entity is "-name AUTO_RESOURCE_SHARING OFF";
    attribute altera_attribute of behaviour : architecture is "-name AUTO_RESOURCE_SHARING OFF";
begin
    -- ...
end behaviour;
```

Does anybody know if this setting can be changed through VHDL attributes?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 7.1 "A specification ... shall always appear either immediately within the same declarative part as that in which the declaration of the named entity appears, or (in the case of specifications that relate to design units ...) immediately within the declarative part associated with the declaration of the design unit, subprogram body, or block statement."  Since -1987. Altera/Intel ignores this requirement as do some simulators (sometimes selectively with a command line option).  An entity declarative part is semantically distinct from an architecture declarative part.

Comment: @user1155120 I'm not sure what you mean with that quote. How do you suggest I change the example? I tried moving the attribute of the entity inside the entity declaration, but the setting is still not applied.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_attribute.htm , this will probably work for the entity, but not for the architecture: `altera_attribute` can only be assigned to entities, instances, ports, and registers.

> *If applied to any other object, the synthesis attribute is ignored.*

This:
https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/08au/labs/Resources/Quartus%20II%20IntegratedSynthesis.pdf

explicitely shows an example that sets the attribute on an architecture, so it is supposedly supported although above document seems to state otherwise.

My guess is that - although you set the attribute on the architecture - you explicitely have to state which entity instance you mean:

```
attribute altera_attribute : string;
attribute altera_attribute of <architecture name>: architecture is "-name AUTO_RESOURCE_SHARING OFF -to ""<entity_name>:<instance_name>""";
```

When I assign the attribute like this, it's at least accepted and listed under "Analysis & Synthesis -> Source Assignments"

Comment: Ok, so the attribute on the architecture is ignored. But on the entity it should work, but it doesn't. Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: found this: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/08au/labs/Resources/Quartus%20II%20IntegratedSynthesis.pdf that explicitely states setting the attribute on the architecture is indeed supported. See my changed answer.